# The equivalent of Curl -k option in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a **Curl** request in php. I started by doing it via the command line this way : `curl -k -X "POST" -d "{\"_format\":\"json\",\"id\":\"152\",\"subscription_type\":\"TEST\"}" -H "Content-type:\ application/json" -H "Accept:\ application/json" https://url`

Now I need to make it in **PHP**, but i don't know what is the equivalent of the *-k* (to turn off the certificate verification) option in **PHP**.

But I've tried something :

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

curl's `-k` option actually sets two different options to false. It [disables the check of the signature in the cert](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html), and it [disables the check of the host name in the cert](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html):

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
```